# Creating IMG Tag With JavaScript, Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, image, styling

Through [ArrowChat Javascript API](http://www.arrowchat.com/documentation/?p=getuser), I'm trying to make avatars show in chat user tabs, that is "on the bar itself", besides in the buddy list and chat window.

I'm editing chat_tab.php (below) for this, starting with a sample static No-Avatar image, and next, I'll try to implement ArrowChat Javascript API functions.

```
<div class="arrowchat_inner_button" id="chattab_inner">
    <div style="float:left" class="arrowchat_username_message">'+shortname+'</div>
</div>
```

All I want to know for now is that if there's something wrong with this script, as it doesn't seem to work.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){var elem=document.createElement("elem"); 
elem.src= "/press/chat/admin/images/img-no-avatar.gif"; 
elem.height="32"; elem.width="32"; document.getElementById("chattab_inner").appendChild(elem);}
</script>
```

Next, I should replace img-no-avatar.gif with the user avatar path, which is getUser(data.a) according to the link above. That's the second in the row I don't know how. (You can preview ArrowChat chat bar at the bottom of the screen in the same page.)

Comment: `elem=document.createElement("elem")`? Unless that's a crazy copy-paste error, it should, I assume, be: `elem=document.createElement("img");`

Comment: My second problem has not resolved...

Answer (score 0):

The element you are created should be "img" not "elem"

you want the parameter for `.createElement()` to be the tag name of the element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var elem=document.createElement("img"); 
    elem.src= "/press/chat/admin/images/img-no-avatar.gif"; 
    elem.height="32";
    elem.width="32";
    document.getElementById("chattab_inner").appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
```

Comment: or `var elem = new Image(32,32);`